# Check/Uncheck using jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to make the check boxes behave like radio buttons in my `ASP .NET MVC` Web Application. I have got about 20-30 check boxes grouped in two. For Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="@riggingType.RiggingTypeId 1" name="RiggingTypePlus" 
       value="@riggingType.RiggingTypeId" 
       checked="@riggingTypeIds.Contains(riggingType.RiggingTypeId)" />

<input type="checkbox" id="@riggingType.RiggingTypeId 2" name="RiggingTypeMinus" 
       value="@riggingType.RiggingTypeId" 
       checked="@riggingTypeIds.Contains(riggingType.RiggingTypeId)" />
```

**Goal:**

I want to make the check boxes to behave in such a way that if a `Plus` Check box is checked then the `Minus` is unchecked automatically and vice versa. I have written following code to try and achieve this functionality:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function () {
  var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(":checkbox");
  var idx = inputs.index(this);
  if (this.name.substring(this.name.length - 4, this.name.length) === "Plus") {
      // just trying to check if I am getting the right it 
      // and I am getting the right id
      // alert(inputs[idx + 1].id);

      // But this does not work
      $("#" + inputs[idx + 1].id).prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

Am I doing something wrong here:

```
$("#" + inputs[idx + 1].id).prop('checked', false);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

I know that I can use the radio buttons and group them by same name but I am rendering the elements in a loop so they all have the same name but different values and I don't want to name them differently because I am using this data on the server side... Is there a better way to do this?

**Answer:**

Got this working using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":checkbox").on('click', function () {

    var $this = $(this);
    var inputs = $this.closest("form").find(":checkbox");
   if ($this.attr('name').substring(this.name.length - 4, this.name.length) === "Plus" && $this.attr('checked')) {
        $this.next().prop('checked', false);
    }
        else
        {
            $this.prev().prop('checked', false);
        }
  });
});
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/24gmnjwm/2/)

Comment: If u make fiddle - i solve ur trouble (it is wrong - have any tags with same id - try to create differents ids

Comment: Both checkboxes have the same id. The the last checkbox will likely always be deselected. Ids should always be unique.

Comment: @KJPrice oh, get it, dont attention on tag, ty

Comment: Try `inputs[idx + 1].prop("id")` instead of `inputs[idx + 1].id`

Comment: I suspect the problem is the `id` selectors. Is there a reason you can't simply use the HTMLElement as a selector? `$(inputs[idx+1]).prop...`

Comment: @KJPrice yes right now the id is same but if I succeed in making the jQuery working I will make the ids Unique...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/24gmnjwm/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":checkbox").on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var inputs = $this.closest("form").find(":checkbox");
    if ($this.attr('name').substring(this.name.length - 4, this.name.length) === "Plus") {
        $this.next().prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `inputs[idx + 1]` is an HTMLElement, not a jQuery object. This will return a function not defined error

Comment: I have tried this and I get the error `id not defined`

Comment: Try `inputs[idx + 1].prop("id")` instead of `inputs[idx + 1].id`. Already commented this on your question.

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi edited, it works now, but not nice to view, if i right understand ur problem - i re-write to more readable and for minus too

Comment: Thanks man I got it working here is the updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/24gmnjwm/2/

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that the "plus" checkbox always appears immediately before its related "minus" checkbox then this will do the trick:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("name").match(/Plus$/)) {
        $(this).next().prop("checked", !$(this).prop("checked"));
    } else {
        $(this).prev().prop("checked", !$(this).prop("checked"));
    }
});
```

sample form:

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="RiggingTypePlus" value="2" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="RiggingTypeMinus" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="RiggingTypePlus" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="RiggingTypeMinus" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="RiggingTypePlus" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="RiggingTypeMinus" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="RiggingTypePlus" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="RiggingTypeMinus" value="5" />
</form>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3x5eec41/2/)

Comment: But this does not work assuming that I just had to copy paste this ? I can check all the check boxes can you make a fiddle?

Comment: It certainly should work if you copy paste it, and if your form HTML is how I imagined it would be rendered (like above, ID can be there or missing doesnt matter)

Comment: I misunderstood your form.  Redid answer to work with what you have.